# Foundation Scripts not loading (custom theme)

Tags: menus, jquery, dropdown

I'm trying to create a custom WP theme with foundation but the menu never seem to work.

After some time I realized that my scripts loaded (I see them in the header - firebug) but not activating. Weird.

This is my functions.php for loading the scripts. Pretty simple:

```
function enqueue_test_scripts() {

/* Original Foundation scripts and styles

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

*/

wp_enqueue_style('style-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/foundation.min.css');

wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/jquery.js', false);
wp_enqueue_script('app', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/app.js', true);
wp_enqueue_script('what-input', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/what-input.js');
wp_enqueue_script('foundation', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/foundation.js',true);

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_test_scripts',0);
```

Just to make sure I tested a quick and simple html menu in index.html and it works. I then dropped it in below the header in the wordpress theme php file and now it's just static - no dropdown effects or anything.

So the scripts are there, they are loaded, but not doing activating.

My only conclusion is that they are in conflict with something but I have no idea what.

Could it have something to do with using jQuery( instead of $(...?

Something else?

Comment: try to add your scripts in the same order than the commented line. js/app.js is the last (in commented line) not when you use wp_enqueue_script.

Comment: Are there errors in browser console? Sounds like broken JS. Also overriding core's jQuery is considered a bad practice in WP.

Answer (score 0):

Benoti

Yes, that was it! Seems app.js needs to be the last item loaded. Here is the final function with a couple of changes for anyone interested:

```
function foundation_scripts() {

wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/jquery.js', false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/foundation.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('what-input', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/what-input.js', false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('app', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/app.js', array('jquery', 'foundation-js'), false, true); }
```